# iOS how do I remove all extra lines in nsstring

Tags: ios, regex

I got a `NSString` like this : `@"\r\nThis is a test.\r\n\r\nHow is the weather?\r\n\r\n"`

I want to trim extra lines so the nesting become: `@"This is a test.\nHowis the weather?\n"`

I have tried :

```
NSMutableString *str = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"\r\nThis is a test.\r\n\r\nHow is the weather?\r\n\r\n"];

NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"^\\r\\n" options:0 error:nil];

[regex replaceMatchesInString:str options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [str length]) withTemplate:@"\n"];
```

I thought ^ stands for the beginning of a line and it should work to remove extra carriage return and line feed but it didn't. Could anyone tell me why and how to solve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Following i found is the easiest way to remove new line `Characters` from string:

```
    NSMutableString *str = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"\r\nThis is a test.\r\n\r\nHow is the weather?\r\n\r\n"];  
    NSString *newString = [[str componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
    NSLog(@"==%@",newString);
```

**OUTPUT IS:**

> This is a test.How is the weather?

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved in two easy steps:

```
NSString *text = @"\r\nThis is a test.\r\n\r\nHow is the weather?\r\n\r\n";

NSLog(@"1 ****%@****", text);

//1. Split the string around the newline character set
NSArray *textLines = [text componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];

NSLog(@"textLines: %@", textLines);

//2. Build the string from the components
NSMutableString *resultText = [NSMutableString new];
for (NSString *line in textLines) {
    if (line.length) {
        [resultText appendFormat:@"%@\n", line];
    }
}

NSLog(@"***%@***", resultText);
```

**Result:**

```
---------------------
This is a test.
How is the weather?
---------------------
```